# Code snippet works in an online IDE but not on my local ghc

Tags: ghc, runhaskell

As a beginner, i wrote a snippet to flip a string's case.

```
module Main
 where

import Data.Char

main=do
  str<-getLine
  putStrLn ( reverser(str) )

reverser:: String -> String 
reverser [] = []
reverser (x:xs) | isUpper x = toLower x : reverser xs
                | otherwise = toUpper x : reverser xs
```

And it worked perfectly on the hackerearth.com's IDE

[IDE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on13v.png)

However,when I tried running the same on my machine, the code is executing endlessly and not coming up with any output nor error.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmPW2.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Been awhile since I've written Haskell, but it looks fine to me. Did you restart the terminal? Your computer could just be derping.

Comment: Confirmed working on a fresh install of GHC  8.0.2. It must be something wrong with your environment.